# RDP client designed for multiple server connections?

Tags: windows, rdp

I need a RDP client that I could share with fellow administrators, so that everybody doesn't have to create the connections for themselves and updating multiple places when something changes.

So, required features:

- organization of connection profiles (tree or something similar)
- ability to set password for whole collection (or better yet, per tree hive *)
- multiuser ready - number of persons accessing central location for connections at the same time
- MDI or tabbed (preferred) interface for open connections
- encryption for password protected file/hive *
- ability to use current logon creditentials *
- file based connection database (so it would be easy to share the file via Dropbox)
- runs in windows
- no bloat

Not required, but would be nice:

- possibility to import RDP connection files *
- SSH/VNC/X11
- Keepass integration for password management *
- runs also on linux *
- free

probably forgot something, but even these features would satisfy.

*-indicates features that mRemote doesnt have (AFAIK) or doesn't implement well enough for me

Comment: I use Terminals, not all the features included but I'm fine with it.
And Alt-Tab is a nice feature that it has on a RDP.

Comment: Been looking for similar tool long ago with no luck. I wonder our gurus answer with a really good software.

Comment: Remmina does some of this.  I didn't like the Microsoft solution, but I take from its very existence that somebody out there likes it.

Answer (score 2):

I've really gotten to like the new [RDCMan](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4603c621-6de7-4ccb-9f51-d53dc7e48047&displaylang=en) from Microsoft.  It's got most of the features that you wanted.  Features that it includes that i really like:

- Right click connection and logoff/disconnect session.  Also list all sessions and log off other user if necessary.
- Undock session and move it to other monitor
- See snapshots of all sessions

Plus there's a powershell script here: [MS Script Library](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/6a6a6b50-577b-49fd-9432-aa679e41361c) that will get all servers from your domain and create a connection list.

I've used most of the other free connection managers: [mRemoteNG](http://www.mremoteng.org/), [Terminals](http://terminals.codeplex.com/), [RemoteDesktopManager](http://remotedesktopmanager.com/) and this one currently is one of the best free ones.

Answer (score 0):

VisionApp remote desktop - awesome app